# Need help choosing between broad match and exact match keyword for organic SEO campaign

Tags: seo, search-engines, google-search, keywords, research

I am getting a mixed response on targeting broad match vs exact match keywords in Google keywords tool for organic seo campaign.

- some say that its not possible to target a broad match keyword using
  on page seo optimisation.
- some say you can only receive that [exact match] search volume of the
  keyword and not the broad match search volume.
- others say that broad match can be targeted but you may likely to end
  up with non relevant traffic.

How does it work exactly? Is it possible to target and rank for a broad match keyword? Or do I end up targeting traffic for the exact match version of it?

Example:

- how to buy a phone - broad match - 50,000,000 search volume
- [how to buy a phone] - exact match - 500 search volume

If I target broad match "how to buy a phone", will I get 50,000 visitors or do I end up with 500?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can absolutely target a broad match keyword using on page SEO. If the content is unique enough it will rank organically. No question about that, now if the broad keyword is competitive all the on page optimization and quality content on the page will not be enough to rank the page.

Search volumes are not accurate don't take what Google tells you to heart. It's an average and estimated number. If you rank in the top 10 for a keyword, the data from Google Webmaster Tools impressions will vary from the estimated impressions from the keyword tool and your AdWords campaign. So pay no attention to either. Other than if it has a high search volume it'll cost you but you'll be getting clicks if your ad is high enough.

If you do broad match decide on other filters such as demographics. Be sure to use negative keywords as well so that you filter out any searches for people looking for informational or free products etc

There are not good equations which will tell you how many visitors you will get based on the keyword you target or match type. There are too many variables. Where you rank who's searching and so many more. At least in Google AdWords you have the option to run multiple adgroups and ads to split test their performance. So that said try both make sure they're ran evenly and monitor their performance.

Comment: ty for your time but i am not looking for adwords . i need advice for organic search rankings.

Comment: @PrakashMoturu, oh so you plan to optimize for keywords with brackets around them?